# Determine if this two-variable piecewise function is continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have this piecewise function and I have to determine if it is continuous in $(0,0)$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sqrt[]{|x|}\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
So I have to prove if
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt[]{|x|}\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}=0$$

Thus I used polar coordinates and got

$$\lim_{\rho\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt[]{\rho|\cos\theta|}\sin^2(\rho\sin\theta)}{\rho^2}$$
I know that $\cos x\leq1, \sin x\leq1$, then
 $$\frac{\sqrt[]{\rho|\cos\theta|}\sin^2(\rho\sin\theta)}{\rho^2}<\frac{\sqrt\rho\sin^2\rho}{\rho^2}=g(\rho)$$
$$\lim_{\rho\to0}g(\rho)=0\implies \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt[]{|x|}\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
However [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20sqrt(abs(x))sin%5E2y%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%20as%20(x,y)%20to%20(0,0)) says the limit does not exist. Why? I thought that this procedure of polar coordinates yields the final result.

Could Wolfram Alpha also consider  complex $x,y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is (essentially) correct (I'd say that $\cos x \le 1, \sin x \le 1$). A similar approach would be to note that $|\sin y| \le |y|$ for all real $y$, and hence for $x^2+y^2 > 0$ we have

$$\frac{\sin^2 y}{x^2+y^2} \le 1$$

and thus

$$|f(x,y)| \le \sqrt{|x|}$$

which clearly shows your limit is correct.

From the message by Wolfram Alpha about the value being dependend on the path in the **complex** space, maybe the reason is that you only consider real $x,y$ while Alpha considers complex values?

Comment: Thank you! You could be right about WA. Can I check the limit only for real x,y in WA?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with it, maybe somebody else can help?